# When should "Dictator" be capitalized?

Tags: nouns, capitalization

I'm wondering whether the word *dictator* should be capitalized.

Is it just an adjective and not an (official) title?

Comment: It's a noun, not an adjective.

Answer (score 10):

It depends on context and preference. If used as a noun, it's not capitalised:

> He was the dictator of Sicily.

If used as a title, it ought to be:

> He proclaimed himself Dictator of Sicily.

And also if used as an honourific:

> He was called Dictator Garibaldi.

Comment: Does anyone proclaim themselves "the Dictator" as a title? More likely to (falsely) assume "The People's Loved One" or some such.

Comment: @JoseK: Removed "the" to make the example a bit clearer.

Comment: Julius Caesar named himself _Dictator perpetuo_: Dictator for Life.

Comment: Of course the denotation and connotation of _dictator_ was very different in Ancient Rome...

Comment: It was an official title for an office in ancient Rome. I don't know of any country today that uses it as an actual title.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, Dictator doesn't have any positive connotations so as @Jon mentions, it would be hard to find it capitalized correctly. In the past for example, Simón Bolívar, a South American General, was proclaimed Dictator of Peru.